# Retrieving all numpy array indices where condition

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, parallel-processing, where-clause

Say I have a numpy array, a, of elements (which do not repeat) `np.array([1,3,5,2,4])`, I would like to retrieve the indices a contains `[4,2]`. Desired output: `np.array([3,4])` as these are the indices the requested elements.

So far, I've tried

```py
np.all(np.array([[1,2,3,4]]).transpose(), axis=1, where=lambda x: x in [1,2])
>>> 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True])
```

But this result does not make sense to me. Elements at indices 2,3 should be False

Perhaps I need to search for one element at a time, but I'd prefer if this operation could be vectorized/fast.

Comment: `ufunc` `where` should be used with an `out` parameter; otherwise the "false" values will be "undefined".  It looks like you are trying to use the `where` like a `if` clause in an list comprehension.  That's not how it works.  I don't think it's useful for you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the function you're looking for is [numpy.isin()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
print(np.where(np.isin(arr, [1,2])))
```

Should give the output you're looking for